# How to convert instance and property in Objective C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert Obj-C unit test to Swift.
In SearchViewController.m I have declared

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

In Tests.m I have this code to expose the searchBar in SearchViewController.m since we don't want to expose it in SearchViewController.h

```
@interface SearchViewController (UnitTest)
@property UISearchBar *searchBar;
@end
```

How can I translate the Obj-C code to Swift? I read on HackingWithSwift that @instance @property translates to class and variable in Swift. In this case, it's already declared in SearchViewController.m Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the property as private :

```
@IBOutlet private var searchBar: UISearchBar!
```

It can be seen by storyboard but not modified from other classes

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple Documentation
[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618657-searchbar)

We can declare UISearchBar like this

```
var searchBar: UISearchBar { get }
```